# CPLEX and Anaconda Python integration error on MacOS

Tags: python-3.x, macos, anaconda, cplex, docplex

I installed Anaconda 1.9.7, the Python version is 3.7.3. Then used

```
conda install -c ibmdecisionoptimization cplex
```

and

```
pip install cplex
```

However, I face this error:

> No module named 'docplex'.

There is nothing on the net for solving this error of integrating CPLEX and Anaconda Python for Mac and Anaconda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that docplex wants to install docloud and that there was no python 3.7 distribution for docloud. This is now fixed. See https://github.com/IBMDecisionOptimization/docplex-examples/issues/18